# How to remove prepositions in a input String using java .split() method?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I tried `String string[] = str.toLowerCase().split("[,\\s?.@]+");`  to reduce expressions in the string input. But I need to reduce prepositions from the string input too. Tried it using `String string[] = str.toLowerCase().split("[,\\s?.@]+","the","for");`

but got error

```
Test.java:15: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int
        String string[] = str.toLowerCase().split("[,\\s?.@]+","the");
                                                               ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

I want the input like: 
Input: `The cat is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal in the world.`
Output :

```
the    
cat
is 
a
domestic
species
small
carnivorous
mammal
the
world
```

Is there a way to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you're looking for is likely `.split("([,\\s?.@]+)|(the)|(for)")`. The split method takes a string representing the delimiter and the number of times it should split (in an overloaded method). It does not take `String...`

Comment: I updated the question with the desired output. And when I tried `.split("([,\\s?.@]+)|(the)|(for)") `, spliting the sentence using space are missing.